# Elastic Search Query equal vs double point

Tags: elasticsearch

What is the difference between

`“query”: “osversion=android”`
and
`“query”: “osversion:android”`

I can't find an explaination for `:`vs`=`.

I get differently results with these. We have Updated Kibana from 4.x to 5.x and reindexed anything. 
Before the update i used `:` and now after the update i didn't get the results and i must use `=` to get it.

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "analyze_wildcard": true,
            "query": "product:PRODUCTNAME"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "log_timestamp": {
              "gte": 1512909497485,
              "lte": 1515501497485,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": []
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "3": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "IOS": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "osversion:ios",
              "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
          },
          "Android": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "osversion:android",
              "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "1": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "uuid",
            "precision_threshold": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Mappings:

```
   "osversion": {
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "type": "keyword",
      "doc_values": true
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you type inside the Kibana search bar needs to conform to the [`query_string` query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax), i.e. the only wy for your query to be correct is to use `:`, as in

```
osversion:android
```

which will retrieve all documents whose `osversion` fields matches `android`.

Instead, if you type

```
osversion=android
```

then the standard analyzer kicks in and the query will search for all documents which have either `osversion` or `android` in any of their analyzed fields, which is quite different.

Comment: Oh ok, so the problem is that double point doesn't work anymore for my query. we have many android and ios version and we want to group them to OS only. `osversion:android*` doesn't work either, the `"analyze_wildcard": true` is setted.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're doing those queries in Kibana or from an adhoc client? In the latter case, can you show the full query and also your mapping?

Comment: I am doing both, Kibana and from a php client.

Comment: Ok it seems that keywords are case-sensitiv.

Comment: `keyword` are not analyzed by default, and used for exact matching, indeed, so yes definitely case-sensitive